# macro keys for Razer BlackWidow Ultimate

Tags: keyboard, 15.04

I bought a new keyboard, a *Razer BlackWidow Ultimate Elite*. All keys will operate until the macro keys M1 to M5.

`xev` gives no output for this keys. Is there a way to use keys with Ubuntu?

```
% lsusb | grep Razer
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 1532:011a Razer USA, Ltd
```

Comment: Wow - sick keyboard you got there ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we need a little Python3 script, taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/474595/427428) (Please go and give @Sergey an upvote **;)**)

I have replaced the product id with my product id `011a`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import usb
import sys

VENDOR_ID = 0x1532  # Razer
PRODUCT_ID = 0x011a  # BlackWidow Ultimate Elite

USB_REQUEST_TYPE = 0x21  # Host To Device | Class | Interface
USB_REQUEST = 0x09  # SET_REPORT

USB_VALUE = 0x0300
USB_INDEX = 0x2
USB_INTERFACE = 2

LOG=sys.stderr.write

class blackwidow(object):
  kernel_driver_detached = False

  def __init__(self):
    self.device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)

    if self.device is None:
      raise ValueError("Device {}:{} not found\n".format(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID))
    else:
      LOG("Found device {}:{}\n".format(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID))

    if self.device.is_kernel_driver_active(USB_INTERFACE):
      LOG("Kernel driver active. Detaching it.\n")
      self.device.detach_kernel_driver(USB_INTERFACE)
      self.kernel_driver_detached = True

    LOG("Claiming interface\n")
    usb.util.claim_interface(self.device, USB_INTERFACE)

  def __del__(self):
    LOG("Releasing claimed interface\n")
    usb.util.release_interface(self.device, USB_INTERFACE)

    if self.kernel_driver_detached:
      LOG("Reattaching the kernel driver\n")
      self.device.attach_kernel_driver(USB_INTERFACE)

    LOG("Done.\n")

  def bwcmd(self, c):
    from functools import reduce
    c1 = bytes.fromhex(c)
    c2 = [ reduce(int.__xor__, c1) ]
    b = [0] * 90
    b[5:5+len(c1)] = c1
    b[-2:-1] = c2
    return bytes(b)

  def send(self, c):
    def _send(msg):
      USB_BUFFER = self.bwcmd(msg)
      result = 0
      try:
        result = self.device.ctrl_transfer(USB_REQUEST_TYPE, USB_REQUEST, wValue=USB_VALUE, wIndex=USB_INDEX, data_or_wLength=USB_BUFFER)
      except:
        sys.stderr.write("Could not send data.\n")

      if result == len(USB_BUFFER):
        LOG("Data sent successfully.\n")

      return result

    if isinstance(c, list):
#      import time
      for i in c:
        print(' >> {}\n'.format(i))
        _send(i)
#        time.sleep(.05)
    elif isinstance(c, str):
        _send(c)

###############################################################################

def main():
    init_new  = '0200 0403'
    init_old  = '0200 0402'
    pulsate = '0303 0201 0402'
    bright  = '0303 0301 04ff'
    normal  = '0303 0301 04a8'
    dim     = '0303 0301 0454'
    off     = '0303 0301 0400'

    bw = blackwidow()
    bw.send(init_old)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To start the script, we need `pyusb` for Python3

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo pip3 install pyusb
```

Save the Python script as `init_blackwidow.py` and set the execution rights. Now start the script with

```
sudo ./init_blackwidow.py
```

Now you can check the keycodes with `xev` …

---

**… until the next reboot :\**

But we can use `/etc/rc.local` and `udev`:

1. Copy the script `init_blackwidow.py` into `/usr/local/bin`
2. Add the line below in `/etc/rc.local`, before the line `exit 0`

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/init_blackwidow.py
   ```

   Now you should have something like this

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   #
   # rc.local
   #
   # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
   # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
   # value on error.
   #
   # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
   # bits.
   #
   # By default this script does nothing.

   /usr/local/bin/init_blackwidow.py

   exit 0
   ```
3. Create a new rule

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="1532", ATTR{idProduct}=="011a", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/init_blackwidow.py"
   ```

   in

   ```
   /etc/udev/rules.d/99-razer_blackwidow.rules
   ```
4. Restart `udev`

   ```
   sudo service udev restart
   ```

   and enjoy …

Comment: I'll know where to run to when I buy a weird keyboard...  **;-)**

Comment: But still have one issue - PhpStorm still doesn't recognize these keys. Tried to bind in Settings -> Keymap - just unable to bind, commands binded in KDE shortcuts it doesn't receive as well. But in other applications all works fine.

Answer (score 3):

## As an alternative to the good anwser of **A.B.** :

---

### Easy install of razer chroma drivers

The following project has support for many Razer chroma drivers. It also activates the Mx keys.

https://github.com/pez2001/razer_chroma_drivers

---

### MacroW - A simple macro player/recorder.

There is an on-the-fly macro recorder/ playback for the M1,M2,M3,M4 and M5 keys called **MacroW**. MacroW is very simple to use (*IMHO as dev*).
If you managed to activate your Mx keys and want to try MacroW you can check it out:

https://github.com/igorbb/MacroW

I would love to get some feedback/ help on it.