# Asus laptop Macro keys mapping

Tags: keyboard, asus

How do I remap the Asus Rog laptop macro keys in Ubuntu 20.04 . All the research I have done has pointed me to procedures on windows OS.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/660262/macro-keys-for-razer-blackwidow-ultimate talks about a keyboard

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add important info and details to the question. As I can find there many ROG models. I expect [that post](https://askubuntu.com/q/660262/26246) didn't work for you too.

Comment: I gleaned some information from it. However this is a different keyboard. I am talking about the ASUS ROG G752VL gaming laptop

Comment: The post is in the Close review queue, due to lack of details. Edit it and add all related info up there. Leave comment only for interaction (comments are cleaned sometimes). Try the test commands explained in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/26246 , see if the keys are detected by Ubuntu. Report by editing the question.

Comment: ok will edit the question and check your link